# Client statistics for npgsql connection

Tags: npgsql

In Microsoft SQL server, I can retrieve the number of bytes sent / received with provider statistics on the connection, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/provider-statistics-for-sql-server

We are switching to PostgreSQL and more specifically, we are using Npgsql to access the database.

I cannot figure out how to retrieve the number of bytes sent over the network to answer our query.

I looked into some Npgsql code, but my understanding of the codebase is lacking and I only see performance counters for .NET Standard there. And these would not return the exact number of bytes that were needed to read the rows for a query. Also, we are still using .NET 4.x and cannot upgrade for several reasons.

Is there a way to get the number of bytes transferred over the network for the result of a query?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there's nothing like that Npgsql at the moment.